# Model property referencing another model - how does it work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm pretty new with ASP.NET MVC, but I know a lot more about PHP. So if I had 2 connected tables in a database, normally I'd connect them with an ID - secondary key.

Example:

Movies:

```
 + ID
 + Title
 + Description
 + Genre

-- Comments --
 + ID
 + MoviesID
 + Comment
```

Thus creating a one to many kind of relationship. But I saw that in ASP.NET MVC people would create models which would reference one another:

```
public class Movie {
    // Annotations not included
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public string Genre {get;set;}
    public List<Comment> Comment {get;set;}
}

public class Comment {
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public Movie Movie {get;set;}
    public string Comment {get;set;}
}
```

So the parts where one model calls another, how does that looks like in the database, how do you fill those up in the database, how do you pass values of one comment/movie class to a database of the other class when you want to create a new row? (if that makes sense - example would be how to insert a movie object in the database for when you upload a new comment in the database.) Or if at least you could give me some source to read about it, because I found nothing.

Of course another question would be if this is smart to do, or should you just do it the "traditional" way, following the pattern I did at the top?

Hope it's understandable, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to is an ORM what stands for Object-Relational Mapping.

Basically ORM helps you treat tables and relations between them as objects. This approach makes programming much more easier in terms of common language for code and database.

ORM tools are widely used also in PHP(search for Proper, Doctrine). For C# you can refer to NHibernate, Entity Framework or micro-ORMs like Dapper. The example you provided as a .NET approach is similar to your approach in PHP. The only difference is that you explicitely mark one property as foreign key. You could change your example to:

```
public class Movie {
   //Annootations not included
   public int ID {get;set;}
   public string Title {get;set;}
   public string Description {get;set;}
   public string Genre {get;set;}
   public List<int> CommentIds {get;set;}
}

public class Comment {
   public int ID {get;set;}
   public int MovieID {get;set;}
   public string Comment {get;set;}
}
```

but this would only load identifiers for related records. When using ORM you can mark property(which in table is an identifier to the another table record) as strong-typed class, what enables you to load all its data from database.

To make long story short - when using ORM you can load whole `Movie` when fetching `Comment` from DB, not only its identifier.

Whole process and its configuration depends on ORM tool you are using, you can use mapping attributes(e.g. in Entity Framework), or fluent mappings(when using NHibernate with Fluent NHibernate). Those tools are quite complex(there are many issues to solve - eager/lazy loading, connection management, session management, LINQ to Entities and many many more, it is impossible to explain it on SO :))

Comment: I took a look on google, didn't know there's a whole concept behind it (ORM). Thank you for the explanation. I'll be honest and say that I don't entirely understand all of which you wrote, but I'll get to the bottom of it, I always do. Your info is still far from unhelpful, I understood most of which you wrote, so thank you very much!! :)

Comment: @NemanjaT - as I wrote, whole ORM concept is quite complex and it is hard to explain having limited space as in SO :) Glad I could help, check some tutorials for Entity Framework, I believe it make all it much more clear :)